# read data from database and show on a multiselect dropdown

Tags: asp.net

here i m showing data from database and showing on textbox...there is  also a multiselect dropdown using multidropdown.dll. I m successfully showing data in the textboxes but what method should i use to show data in the multidropdown.
what code should i use to show data in the multidropdown instead of .........
multiselect dropdown has following code:

code to read data from database and showing in textbox and multidropdown:

```
<multidropdownLib:multidropdown id="multidropdown1"runnat="server"/>
 sqldatareader dr =cmd.executereader();
 while(dr.read())
 {
 textbox1.text=dr["column_name"].tostring();

  multidropdown1................=dr["column_name"].....
 }
```

Comment: is multiselect dropdown has a datasource property ?

Comment: Multiselect dropdown is coming by the answer of blgnklc ...i m not sure about ur questins answer

Answer (score 0):

DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

```
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String)));
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(System.String)));

dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "Apple"     ,"1"  });
dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "Orange"    ,"2"  });
dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "Pear"      ,"3"  });
dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "Banana"    ,"4"  });
dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "Grapes"    ,"5"  });
dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "Strawberry","6"  });

MultiDropDown1.DataSource = dt1;
MultiDropdown1.DataTextField = "Name";
MultiDropdown1.DataValueField = "ID";
```

reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/219977/MultiDropDown-A-multiple-selection-Dropdown-contro

Comment: this is for including items, but i want to read data from database and show it in the multiple selection-dropdown-control